# Jenkins: "builds" directory doesn't contain the artifacts in each build

Tags: jenkins, build, workspace

I have configured jenkins in my host with a docker container, then I have created a simple MY-JOB process.

The `builds` directory of MY-JOB links to:

```
/var/jenkins_home/jobs/MY-JOB/builds/1
```

This contains only:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.4K Jan 18 15:05 build.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6 Jan 18 15:05 changelog.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  34K Jan 18 15:05 log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  131 Jan 18 15:05 revision.txt
```

But **I have no artifacts in the "1" directory**.

The only path where I can find the result of the build seems to be the following:

```
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/MY-JOB/
```

But this is the working directory, so every time is erased.

How can I configure jenkins in order to put the result of the build in the relative numbered folder under "builds"?

Answer (score 0):

The task can be made adding a post-build action to archive the build result.

The only thing to do is configure the artifacts to archive.

After the build, an "archive" folder is created in the numbered folder of the build:

```
/var/jenkins_home/jobs/MY-JOB/builds/1/archive
```

The archive folder contains the built artifact.